# OpenCV convert Python code to Java

Tags: java, python, opencv

I have the following Python code:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(11,11))
kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel2,iterations = 1)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel1,iterations = 7)
```

I'm trying to convert it to Java. This is my current version:

```
double thresh = Imgproc.threshold(gray, gray, 5, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);
Mat kernel1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(11, 11));
Mat kernel2 = Mat.ones(3, 3, CvType.CV_8U);
Mat erosion = new Mat();
Imgproc.erode(gray, erosion, kernel2);
Mat dilation = new Mat();
Imgproc.dilate(erosion, dilation, kernel1);
```

Right now I'm unable to find a place where `thresh` parameter should be applied and also I'm not using the `iterations` parameter for `Imgproc.erode` and `Imgproc.dilate` methods because the method signature in this case also requires additional `Point anchor` parameter which I do not have right now.

How to properly convert this code to Java?

**UPDATED**

I do the following translation:

```
Mat erosion = new Mat();
Imgproc.erode(gray, erosion, kernel2, new Point(), 1);
Mat dilation = new Mat();
Imgproc.dilate(erosion, dilation, kernel1, new Point(), 7);
```

and looks like it is working as expected but I'm not sure about `new Point()` Is it a correct translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the `dilate` declarations in `C++/Python/Java`:

```
C++: void dilate(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray kernel, 
        Point anchor=Point(-1,-1),
        int iterations=1,
        int borderType=BORDER_CONSTANT,
        const Scalar& borderValue=morphologyDefaultBorderValue() )

Python: cv2.dilate(src, kernel[, dst
            [, anchor[, iterations[, borderType[, borderValue]]]]]) → dst

Java: static void dilate(Mat src, Mat dst, Mat kernel, Point anchor, int iterations)
```

Because there is no default value for `anchor` if you want to use the param `iterations`. So pass `new Point(-1,-1)` is a better choice.

```
Imgproc.dilate(src, dst, kernel, new Point(-1,-1), iterations);
```